# javascript 2D array - sorting and merging

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a 2D array like below:

```
1230 | this is a test
1278 | my new test
1230 | test2
7654 | testing...
```

I want to transform the array so that values are unique in the first column and the second column stores the concatenated text associated with that particular value. See example below.

```
1230 | this is a test -- test2
1278 | my new test
7654 | testing...
```

I understand I should first sort the array by its first column and then do the merging.

Here is the code for sorting the array by the first column:

```
var x = exp_arr.sort(function(a,b){ return a[0] > b[0] ? 1 : -1; });
alert(x);
```

I am a bit lost about how to do the merging. Your suggestions are most welcome

Comment: **Merge** by copying the items to a new array if the "id" is not present and merging if it is. **Sort** the resulting array passing a custom comparator function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `reduce` command like so:

```
var array = [[1230, "this is a test"], [1278, "my new test"], [1230, "test2"], [7654, "testing..."]];

var result =
    array.reduce(function(ob, ar) {
              if (!(ar[0] in ob.nums)) {
                  ob.nums[ar[0]] = ar
                  ob.result.push(ar);
              } else
                  ob.nums[ar[0]][1] = (ob.nums[ar[0]][1]) + " -- " + ar[1];

              return ob
          }, {nums:{}, result:[]}).result
    .sort(function(a,b) {
        return a[0] - b[0];
    });
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/tpvL5fbf/).

[Reduce documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

Comment: Thank you so much. The link to the documentation was very helpful indeed :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
var x = exp_arr.sort(function(a,b){ return a[0] > b[0] ? 1 : -1; }).filter((function() {
    var prev = [null];
    return function(item) {
        if(prev[0] === item[0]) {
            prev[1] += ' -- ' + item[1];
            return false;
        }
        prev = item;
        return true;
    };
}()));
```

**Explanation:**
The filter function takes advantage of the fact that the array is already sorted. So every element is compared with the previous element (herefore a closure was used to save the previous element). If the previous element has the same id, we append the string to the previous element.

Here is the [jsfiddle-demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rkuf1jq0/)

Answer (score 1):

First group array elements with the same first value into object whose keys are the first element, and values are arrays of second elements:

```
groups = array.reduce(function(result, elt) {
    result[elt[0]] = (result[elt[0]] || []).concat(elt[1]);
    return result;
});
```

Then map the object back into an array, by joining the members of each key's array with `--`.

```
Object.keys(groups).map(function(key) { return [key, groups[key].join(' -- '); })
```

Or, taking a leaf out of @friedi's book, taking advantage of sorting the array first, but using `reduce` instead of `filter`, which is slightly simpler because it means we do not need a IIFE to close around a previous item:

```
array.sort(sortfunc).reduce(result, item) {
    var prev = result[result.length-1] || [];
    if (prev[0] === item[0]) {
        prev[1] += " -- " + item[1];
    } else {
        result.push(item);
    }
}, []);
```

Either is far more readable than the accepted solution.